# Camera doesn't stay attached to parent

Tags: game-engine, camera, parent, error

[image] –

[image]my player is actually an invisible cube and a parented camera. I want to make a first person player. The problem is that my camera even thow it's parented to the cube doesn't stay attached to the cube the whole time. When i play everything seems fine but when i change a scene and come back to the previus scene, the camers is dislocated, it might even be out of the room. So the movement gets weird and wrong. When i press exit, the camera is still cube's child *i can see the line connecting them* but the camera is far away. I want them to stay together. If someone could help me, as soon as possible, it would be great because it's for a big uniwork i have to finish soon. Thank you.[image]

Comment: maybe share your cube + camera? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots i am uploading it right now, it will be ready in a few minutes. Thank you

Comment: Welcome, assuming this relates to using game engine... if not revert tag edit.

Comment: @batFINGER yes, thank you. UPBGE

Comment: @moonboots it takes a little longer than i thought to upload. Here are two images, one before playing and one after.

Comment: @batFINGER [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=ned8WSO0" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ned8WSO0/)